# What is the probability all the sums are distinct?

Tags: probability

Say we sample with replacement $n$ integers from the range $\{1,\dots,s\}$ independently and place them in an array $A$ of length $n$. Now say we compute the sums of all contiguously indexed subarrays of $A$.

Say, for example,

$$A = (3,2,1,2)$$

The subarrays are $(3),(2),(1),(2), (3,2), (2,1), (1,2),(3,2,1), (2,1,2),(3,2,1,2)$.
We would be given the sums $(3, 2, 1, 2, 5, 3, 3, 6, 5, 8)$.

What is the probability that all the sums are distinct?

Comment: Your example A = (3, 2, 1, 2) makes me think we are sampling with replacement since 2 shows up twice.  I just want to clarify if that is definitely the case.  So, if n=5 and s=10, when we construct A from {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 20}, we might end up with A = (3, 3, 7, 7, 7)?

Comment: Where does this problem come from?  Is there any reason to expect to find a solution in closed form?

Comment: @KurtSchwanda It is sampling with replacement. Thank you I will clarify.

Comment: @saulspatz It's for my own personal interest. It is not too hard to compute the prob all the values in $A$ are distinct and it also has a nice asymptotic form. I was hoping something similar might be possible here.  If an exact answer is too hard, bounds would be interesting too.

Comment: Is this your third variant of the same question? It's an interesting problem for sure but lol.

Comment: Fair enough.  It might be fruitful to start by considering the question, for a given $s$ what is the largest $n$ so that there exists a sequence of length $n$ with distinct subarray sums?

Comment: @RushabhMehta Well.. yes  :)  There are plenty more I have solved myself too.

Comment: @saulspatz That turned out to be quite a tricky question. For $s=1,\dots,12$ the answers are $1,2,3,3,4,5,6,6,7,8,8,9$.